# groovy execute process doesnt work

Tags: shell, groovy, execute

i have the following groovy which for some reasons does not seems to be executing. If i paste the command directly on console then that command runs fine and give results.

```
def process  = "find . -name '*.java' -o -name '*.jsff' -o -name '*.jspx' -not -path '*/noship/*' | xargs grep '${finalStr}'".execute()
    process.text.eachLine{
        println it  
    }
```

what is wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to execute is a shell script, not an OS command. You need to invoke the shell (`sh -c '...'`) to parse and execute this string. Something like:

```groovy
def process = ['sh', '-c', "find . -name '*.java' -o -name '*.jsff' -o -name '*.jspx' -not -path '*/noship/*' | xargs grep '${finalStr}'"].execute()
```

---

And I would advise against such `GString` substitutions (`${finalStr}`), because special symbols inside `finalStr` can break that shell command. Instead, I'd use shell substitution:

```groovy
def process = ['sh', '-c', "find . -name '*.java' -o -name '*.jsff' -o -name '*.jspx' -not -path '*/noship/*' | xargs grep \"\$1\"", 'sh', finalStr].execute()
```

Here all the arguments after the shell command are mapped to shell positional parameters `$0`, `$1`, `$2` etc., so `finalStr` becomes `$1`.

---

But the right thing™ to do is not to use the shell at all - `find` has all the power to do what you need. But we have to break the command into individual parts in order to execute it:

```groovy
def process = ['find', '.',
        '(',
        '-name', '*.java',
        '-o', '-name', '*.jsff',
        '-o', '-name', '*.jspx',
        '-not', '-path', '*/noship/*',
        ')',
        '-exec', 'grep', '--', finalStr, '{}', '+'
    ].execute()
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use single-quoted strings to avoid having someone later get confused when adding a $var, and the GString attempts to expand it?

Comment: Maybe, but then I'll be forced to escape all those single quotes inside the command. And if I change them to double quotes, then someone could insert `$something` inside them and the shell will expand it, which may also be confusing.